# How to tell if mysterious programs in nethogs listing are malware?

Tags: networking, malware

This is what I see in Nethogs:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm concerned about the listings with PID `?`, running as `root`. How can I find out what these are? I'm running Linux Mint 14.

Please let me know what other information I should include.

Comment: Are you running nethogs as root? `netstat -tap` can also show programs related to the connections (if it runs as root). The IPs seems to be some japan yahoo pages.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those are TCP connections that were used to make an outgoing connection to a website. You can tell from the trailing `:80` which is the port that's used for HTTP connections to web servers, typically. After the 3 way TCP connection handshake has completed the connections are left in a "wait to close" state.

This bit is your local system's IP address and that's the port that was used to make the connection to the remote web server:

```
IP: 192.168.0.100  PORT: 50161
```

#### Example

Here's output from my system using `netstat -ant`:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:54125          198.252.206.25:80           TIME_WAIT
```

Notice the state at the end? It's TIME_WAIT. You can further convince yourself of this by adding the `-p` switch so we can see what process is bound/associated to this particular connection:

```
$ sudo netstat -antp | grep 192.168.1.20:54125
$
```

This shows that no process was affiliated with this.

Comment: So for non-networking-savvy users, in short... these are not separate processes at all but are connections which were made by my web browser, and which are waiting to close? (In `netstat` I can see their state is `LAST_ACK`.)

Comment: @AlexD - yes they're waiting to be closed.

Comment: Thx vm! I suspected they were from firefox, but the root user made me nervous... Using `netstat -ant` showed all 15 connections (most (or all?) were to google gru- servers) of :443 ssh, and they were the ESTABILISHED kind. Then I force closed firefox with 12 open tabs (to easily restore session), and ran that cmd again, and all connections went to TIME_WAIT, and most just vanished!

Comment: I am seeing these on my ubuntu server where no browser instance is running. Only nginx is running. Can these connections be opened by client browsers?